# Why does Firebase think the key contains . when setting a new value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to insert an object into Firebase using the exact method outlined in the android-quickstart tutorials. However, when I try to add a new user with the key of `uid` it throws the exception:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableKey(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:120)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:103)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:104)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:293)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:166)
        ....
```

The code being run just before this is:

```
/* FirebaseUser is created with emailAndPassword just before this  and the
 * uid is retrieved from that new user.
 */
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db = db.child("users");
db = db.child(uid);
Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to insert user at" + uid );
Log.d(TAG, db.toString());
db.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User created at " + uid);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

And the output just before the exception occurs is:

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( gDGy7BIGvQWjnQ7yZVCsdkIbAzx1 ).
D/SignUpActivity: Attempting to insert user at gDGy7BIGvQWjnQ7yZVCsdkIbAzx1
D/SignUpActivity: https://my-app.firebaseio.com/users/gDGy7BIGvQWjnQ7yZVCsdkIbAzx1
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( gDGy7BIGvQWjnQ7yZVCsdkIbAzx1 ).
```

The `uid` from the FirebaseUser clearly doesn't have any illegal characters in it so I'm not sure where that exception is coming from.

**Edit:**
user is a User object with email and username fields initialized and a few other uninitialized fields (name and location) that haven't been implemented yet. This `setValue()` operation was working in a previous iteration of the code. In the current iteration User also implements Parcelable so that Users can be passed between activities.

Current User declaration:

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private Location location;

    public User() {}
        public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    protected User(Parcel in) {
        username = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        location = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() { ... };

        public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    protected User(Parcel in) {
        username = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        location = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

Comment: what does `user` contain?

Comment: At which line of code points that error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @PeterHaddad user is a User object that contains two strings for the users email and username.

Comment: @AlexMamo The exception occurs during execution of db.setValue()

Comment: @tchell Are you using `setValue()` also in another part of your code?

Comment: `Invalid key: .` This means the key is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may become clear from my most recent edit but it seems that implementing Parcelable and trying to read/write uninitialized fields is what is causing the problem. If I remove the uninitialized fields from the Parcelable implementation the setValue() works as expected.

```
    protected User(Parcel in) {
        username = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        //name = in.readString();
        //location = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(username);
        dest.writeString(email);
        //dest.writeString(name);
        //location.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    }
```